# A parity learning question

Tags: lg.learning

Let us define a class of functions over a set of $n$ bits. Fix two distributions $p, q$ that are "reasonably" different from each other (if you like, their variational distance is at least $\epsilon$, or something similar).

Now each function $f$ in this class is defined by a collection of $k$ indices $S$, and is evaluated as follows: If the parity of the selected bits is 0, return a random sample from $p$, else return a random sample from $q$.

**Problem**: Suppose I'm given oracle access to some $f$ from this class, and while I know $\epsilon$ (or some other measure of distance), I don't know $p$ and $q$.

> Are there any bounds on the number of calls I need to make to
>   PAC-learn $f$ ? Presumably my answer will be in terms of $n, k$ and $\epsilon$.

**Note**: I didn't specify the output domain. Again, I'm flexible, but for now let's say that $p$ and $q$ are defined over a finite domain $[1..M]$. In general, I'd also be interested in the case when they are defined over ${\mathbb R}$ (for example, if they're Gaussians)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the model. What do you specify in an oracle call?  Are the examples always drawn from the distribution specified by the target?

Comment: In an oracle call, you invoke f() and it returns a value.

Comment: So depending on the target function $f \in F$, either $p$ or $q$ is always used to generate examples?  (I assume you are pac learning some class $F$.)

Comment: Yes that is correct. the problem is to learn which one (or learn the parity bit being used)

Comment: Then who cares which distribution is the "target"?  I think the standard PAC bound from Occam's Razor Theorem simply applies. Just find a consistent hypothesis from $F$ after drawing $O(\lg(|F|)/\epsilon)$ examples (where $\epsilon$ is the target error rate, not distance). What am I missing?

Comment: You may not be missing anything - I'm a n00b at PAC-learning. But it's possible I didn't model the original problem correctly (it came from a post on genetic algorithms)

Comment: What is the right COLT model for this problem? What are the bounds on a solution with and without the wrinkle? The fate of a field depends on the answers to these questions. No pressure :)

Comment: I am not sure how you adapt the PAC model to this model. But it seems that it's enough to be able to distinguish $p$ from $q$ with probability $1 - 1/(2k)$ and then you can get the $f(x)$ values for $k$ linearly independent $x$ and use gaussian elimination to find $f$ (since $f$ is linear). distinguishing two well-separated gaussians will be easy for example.

Answer (score 6):

**The discussion in the comments below indicades that I have misunderstood the question.  My answer is premised on the Oracle taking no input and returning $(x, f(x))$ where $x \sim p$ or $x \sim q$, depending on $f \in F$. This is apparently not what's being asked.**

---

Because the target distribution is fixed for every target $f^* \in F$, the PAC-sample upper bound applies (this follows from the fact that the target distribution for this bound can even completely depend on $f^*$). Hence, 
$$
m \le \tilde{O}\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\left(\mathrm{VC}(F) + \log(1/\delta) \right) \right)
$$
examples should suffice to find a hypothesis of error $\le \epsilon$ w.p. $\ge 1-\delta$. Note -- after seeing these examples, one needs to find a consistent hypothesis from $F$, and this may not be tractable.

On the other hand, one can get a nearly matching lower bound even for the case of $p=q=U$, the uniform distribution, where $m \ge \Omega(\mathrm{VC}(F))$ examples are still required (this can be improved slightly).

The variational distance between $p$ and $q$, as well as $k$ may play a role in the small gap between these bounds, but I doubt it.

Comment: The typical PAC-learning setting has an oracle $(f,D)$ that draws a sample $x$ from distribution $D$, and returns $(x, f(x))$. This is not the setting described in Suresh's question or the blog post that inspired it: http://bit.ly/YtwdST. In both of these, the oracle *is* the function $f$, and the learner is free to submit any element from the instance set (bitstrings of length $n$). Lev, does your answer assume an oracle of the first type, or the second type? If the second type, are we still talking about PAC-learning?

Comment: I see. In PAC, the "oracle" usually is thought of as a button which returns $(x, f(x))$ where $x \sim D$.  The Oracle you describe is called a "membership query" to $f$.  My answer only applies to the former.  If you only membership queries, how do you find out any information about $p$ or $q$ using Suresh's framework?  Let's say $p=q$ for simplicity.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. So in the case Suresh described, the  "membership query" oracle works as follows (I presume you've put this entity in quotes because the oracle can return a real value, not just a boolean is-a-member/not-a-member answer): if the parity of the effective attributes is 1, then the result returned is drawn from distribution $p$. Otherwise, the result is drawn from distribution $q$. There's an additional wrinkle. The oracle remembers all its previous answers, and returns them if queried with the same input. In other words, it is deterministic.

Comment: I don't understand.  If the oracle is simply a function $f$ and you query it by giving it $x$, doesn't it just return $f(x)$? How does $p$ or $q$ come in to play if the learner is generating $x$ himself?  I think I've been failing to understand this basic point all along...

Comment: For $p=\mathcal N(+0.25, 1)$ and $q = \mathcal N(-0.25, 1)$, the pseudocode of the oracle for the problem with the "wrinkle" is given at the bottom of this reddit comment: http://bit.ly/XvVMC4 (`def fitness() ...`). I can't inline the code because SE doesn't allow newlines in comments. To obtain the "non-wrinkly" version of the problem, just remove the line `random_number_generator.set_seed(x)`.

Comment: I don't understand your reddit comment either -- is the oracle the "fitness" function?  Can you simply explain how the oracle works?  How do you call the oracle -- what is its input? What does it output? Do you give an example $x$ and the oracle gives $f(x)$? Do you give an example $x$ and the oracle returns some function of $f(x)$ and $p$ or $q$?  Do you call the oracle with no input? etc.

Comment: I think I know where the confusion lies. First some clarification: In the "wrinkly" variant of the problem, the oracle is exactly "`fitness`". In "non-wrinkly" variant, the oracle is "`fitness`" sans the line `random_number_generator.set_seed(x)`. In both variants of the problem, the input to the oracle can be any string of bits of length n. In both variants, the output is a rational.

Comment: Here's where I think the confusion lies: In both variants of the problem the concept and hypthothesis space are not sets of functions but the set of all combinations of $k$ integers between 1 and n. These are the $k$ effective attributes. The task is to learn them. The oracle for when $k=4$ is given by "`fitness`"